# Accelerometer - Tilt Detection

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, detection, motion

I'm using the [MMA8453Q](http://www.nxp.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA8453Q.pdf) for tilt detection of 45 degree in any axis. I'm a newbie to embedded devices. I have a few questions.

1) Should I be using Transient detection or Motion detection for my use case? I referred the [Application note AN4071](http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4071.pdf?fpsp=1). But, I'm unable to understand the use case scenario for both transient detection & motion detection with respect to tilt detection.

2) I'm currently using Transient detection. But, it is detecting only abrupt shakes. When I turn it slowly, it doesn't detect the tilt even if the board is in 90 degree. Is there any specific reason for that?

Register configurations are:

```
CTRL_REG1 - 0x1A  (100 Hz ODR & F_READ)
XYZ_DATA_CFG - 0x00 (2g)
HP_FILTER_CUTOFF - 0x01 (2 Hz)
TRANSIENT_CFG - 0x1E (Enabling all axes & latch)
TRANSIENT_THS - 0x0B (For approx 45 degree tilt)
TRANSIENT_COUNT - 0x05 (50 ms debounce count for 100 Hz ODR)
```

Kindly suggest me which registers I should change to detect if I move the board really slowly. Any kind of related suggestions or explanations are much appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried reducing the cut-off frequency. But, I couldn't reduce it below 2 Hz, as it started detecting interrupts even when it is stationary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be much clearer than this...

> The transient function (with HPF enabled) is different from 
>   the motion detection embedded function in MMA8451, 2, 3Q.
>
> Refer to Freescale application note AN4070 for details on the motion
>    detection. The intended use of these functions is different.
>
> A.  The embedded motion function triggers an interrupt when an
>   y of the enabled axes has exceeded a set acceleration 
>   threshold.
>
> •   Motion detection is useful when the device may be tilted
>    in an orientation and the interest is to know if the 
>   acceleration in one axis has crossed a specified threshold amount measured from 0g. The motion detection 
>   analyzes change in threshold considering both static and dynamic acceleration.
>
> B.  The transient detection embedded function compares whether any of the enabled axes has exceeded a set change 
>   in acceleration disregarding the static acceleration. The data that is compared to the threshold to be exceeded is 
>   high-pass filtered data.
>
> •   Transient detection is useful when the device may be tilted in an orientation (i.e., there is some non-zero reading 
>   on one or more of X, Y and Z) and the interest is more 
>   on the dynamic acceleration crossing a specified threshold 
>   amount in a short amount of time (frequency being the reciprocal of time) regardless of what the current value is.

Comment: Yes. I went through this in that application note. So, does that mean that transient detection threshold is how fast the tilt should happen to get detected?

Comment: It says that for the application you describe you should be using motion detection.